# How to load the training data to OpenCV from UCI?

Tags: c++, csv, opencv, training-data

I have a character/font dataset found in UCI repository:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Character+Font+Images

Take any CSV file as an example, for instance 'AGENCY.csv'. I am struggling to load it to the OpenCV using a c++ functions. It seems that the structure of the dataset is quite different from what normally assumed in function

```
cv::ml::TrainData::loadFromCSV
```

Any ideas to do it neatly or I need to pre-process the csv files directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load csv file like this:
CvMLData data;
data.read_csv( filename )

For details on opencv ml csv, Refer this page:
http://www.opencv.org.cn/opencvdoc/2.3.1/html/modules/ml/doc/mldata.html

Comment: Thanks, do you have maybe an example?